# Formik Real-time Validation before submitting a form or before clicking away from a field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Formik Doesn't start validation when you start typing in a field, it only start validating when you submit your form or click away from a field.
how can i make formik start validating as soon as you type in a field.

I have discovered that if you remove touched."formik item", it will start validating real-time but the problem with that is when you start typing in one field it affects all fields as well.

like when you use onchange event to monitor a field real-time.

```
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { REGEX } from "../../../Constants/Regex/Regex";

const FormikPractice = () => {
  const { ONLY_NUMBER_THREE_DIGIT } = REGEX;

  const CustomerSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    parameter: Yup.string()
      .required("پر کردن این فیلد الزامی است")
      .matches(ONLY_NUMBER_THREE_DIGIT, "only Three Numbers"),
    message: Yup.string()
      .required("پر کردن این فیلد الزامی است")
      .matches(ONLY_NUMBER_THREE_DIGIT, "only Three Numbers"),
    blackList: Yup.string()
      .required("پر کردن این فیلد الزامی است")
      .matches(ONLY_NUMBER_THREE_DIGIT, "only Three Numbers"),
    screen: Yup.string()
      .required("پر کردن این فیلد الزامی است")
      .matches(ONLY_NUMBER_THREE_DIGIT, "only Three Numbers"),
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      parameter: "",
      message: "",
      blackList: "",
      screen: "",
    },
    validationSchema: CustomerSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => console.log(0),
  });

  const { errors, touched, handleSubmit, getFieldProps, values } = formik;

  // const setInputValue = (key, value) => {
  //   formik.setFieldValue({
  //     ...formik.values,
  //     [key]: value,
  //   });
  // };

  return (
    <form
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2,1fr)",
        gap: "1rem",
        margin: "2rem",
      }}
      autoComplete="off"
      noValidate
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <TextField
        label={"parameter"}
        name="parameter"
        id="parameter"
        // onChange={(e) => setInputValue("parameter", e.target.value)}
        inputProps={{ maxLength: 3 }}
        value={formik.values?.parameter}
        {...getFieldProps("parameter")}
        error={Boolean(touched.parameter && errors.parameter)}
        helperText={touched.parameter && errors.parameter}
      />
      <TextField
        label={"message"}
        name="message"
        id="message"
        // onChange={(e) => setInputValue("message", e.target.value)}
        inputProps={{ maxLength: 3 }}
        value={formik?.values?.message}
        {...getFieldProps("message")}
        error={Boolean(touched.message && errors.message)}
        helperText={touched.message && errors.message}
      />
      <TextField
        label={"blackList"}
        name="blackList"
        id="blackList"
        // onChange={(e) => setInputValue("blackList", e.target.value)}
        inputProps={{ maxLength: 3 }}
        value={formik.values?.blackList}
        // {...getFieldProps("blackList")}
        error={Boolean(touched.blackList && errors.blackList)}
        helperText={touched.blackList && errors.blackList}
      />
      <TextField
        label={"screen"}
        name="screen"
        id="screen"
        // onChange={(e) => setInputValue("screen", e.target.value)}
        inputProps={{ maxLength: 3 }}
        value={formik.values?.screen}
        // {...getFieldProps("screen")}
        error={Boolean(touched.screen && errors.screen)}
        helperText={touched.screen && errors.screen}
      />
      <Button sx={{ gridColumn: "1/-1" }} type="submit" variant="contained">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default FormikPractice;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I simply had to set the field touched when the field changes:

```js
<TextInput
  name="myInput"
  label="myInput"
  value={formik.values.myInput}
  onBlur={() => formik.setFieldTouched('myInput', true)}
  onChange={(event) => {
    formik.setFieldValue('myInput', event.target.value);
    if (!formik.touched.myInput) formik.setFieldTouched('myInput', true);
  }}
  error={formik.touched.myInput && formik.errors.myInput}
  helperText={formik.touched.myInput && formik.errors.myInput}
/>
```

If that is not enough, you could try to [manually trigger the field validation](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#manually-triggering-validation) in the `onChange` function by adding `formik.validateField('myInput')`.